# Accessing Hardware Sensor Data in Mac OS

Tags: macos, cpu, hardware, cpu-usage, macos-catalina

I recently switched from Ubuntu to a MacBook Pro running Catalina and I am trying to programmatically access the hardware sensor data for things such as fan speed, CPU temp, etc. I have seen such programs [like this](https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp) that get CPU temp and such but I would like to know where the sensor data is stored. I know in Ubuntu temperature is stored in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp`, but what is the equivalent of this in Mac OS?

Comment: Afaik there's no equivalent filesystem representation in MacOS. This is handled by `AppleSMC.kext`, being private API it's not officially documented. However there are handy libraries that should give you a head start https://github.com/beltex/libsmc https://github.com/beltex/SMCKit . If you happen to use it your program will not be eligible to be distributed through official Apple AppStore. But that's still fine for personal use and open sourcing.

Comment: Ok perfect. Thank you!